# Short and efficient Ruby code for transforming array of words to shuffled and comma separated string, with an "and" before the last word?

Tags: ruby, string, interpolation, shuffle

I would like to transform such array:

```
["apple","banana","pineapple","plum","pear"]
```

to

```
I like plum, pineapple, banana, pear *and* apple.
```

My current code is like:

```
%Q{
   I like #{%w[apple banana pineapple plum pear].shuffle.yield_self{|q| [q[0..-2].join(", "),q[-1]].join(" and ") }}
  }
```

Is there any more %w[clever clean shorter efficient rubyesque].magic() approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to offer two solutions. Neither mutates the array that is passed to the method as an argument.

```
arr = ["apple", "banana", "pineapple", "plum", "pear"]
```

**#1**

```
 def to_sentence(arr)
  *all_but_last, last = arr.shuffle
  all_but_last.join(', ') << ' and ' << last
end
```

```
to_sentence(arr)
  #=> "pear, plum, pineapple, apple and banana"
to_sentence(arr)
  #=> "banana, pear, pineapple, plum and apple"
to_sentence(arr)
  #=> "banana, plum, apple, pineapple and pear"
to_sentence(arr)
  #=> "banana, pineapple, pear, apple and plum"
```

**#2**

```
 def to_sentence(arr)
  arr.shuffle.join(', ').sub(/,(?!.*,)/, ' and')
 end
```

```
 to_sentence(arr)
   #=> "banana, plum, pear, apple and pineapple"
 to_sentence(arr)
   #=> "pear, plum, pineapple, banana and apple"
 to_sentence(arr)
   #=> "apple, pineapple, plum, pear and banana"
 to_sentence(arr)
   #=> "apple, plum, pear, pineapple and banana"
```

The regular expression matches a comma that is not followed later in the string by another comma (that is, it matches the last comma in the string). `(?!.*,)` is a *negative lookahead*.

The regular expression could also be written

```
/.*\K,/
```

`.*` matches any character other than line terminators, as many as possible (including commas), because `*` is by default *greedy*. `\K` then resets the start of the match to the current location in the string (right before the last comma) and discards any previously-consumed characters from the match that is returned. A comma is then matched, which necessarily is the last comma in the string.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is more clever or cleaner, but here we go:

```
def to_sentence(ary)
  ary = ary.dup.shuffle
  [ary.pop, ary.join(', ')].reverse.join(' and ')
end
```